# White space in HTML what's better to use?

Tags: html, whitespace

When wanting to add whitespace in html what's the best option?

Let's say I have two `<p>` tags open and close but want space between them via HTML.
Would it be better to use `<br>` or just an empty `<p> </p>` line?

Comment: Better still use a CSS padding on your P tags

Comment: The down votes are pretty harsh. Question is clear enough. Everyone has to learn sometime!

Comment: Yeah exactly just a simple question and -3 downvotes. thanks geedubb ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Neither. A double line break is always wrong. An empty paragraph makes no sense.

This sort of presentational detail is the job of CSS.

If you want a margin, use one of [the `margin` properties](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/box.html#margin-properties).

Comment: Thanks! I already thought CSS was a better idea but then again what's the use of a br tag. When should I use it?

Comment: The most common example is a postal address. The new lines have meaning, but aren't new paragraphs.

Comment: @Thibmaekelbergh: Or for line breaks within a paragraph.

Comment: so apart from that I should never use a br tag?

Comment: There are other times, Poetry for example. The key is that it it is a meaningful new line without being the start of a new idea.

Answer (score 1):

The best option is to use [**Cascading Style Sheets**](http://www.w3.org/Style/CSS/Overview.en.html) to add spacing rather than additional HTML markup.

Answer (score 0):

You do this by adding a `margin` to the `p` elements using CSS or `style` attributes.